# Issues in migrating older ExoPlayer API code to version 2.16.1

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I have the following code using ExoPlayer `2.4.0` API that simply plays a video. I was trying to migrate it to the latest API version (`2.16.1`), but many of the APIs and my used code don't work there anymore. For instance, `newSimpleInstance()` isn't recognized anymore, etc.

How can I update my code to the latest API?

Here is my code so far using ExoPlayer `2.4.0`:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://dash.akamaized.net/akamai/bbb_30fps/bbb_30fps.mpd");

// bandwidthmeter is used for getting default bandwidth
BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();

// track selector is used to navigate between video using a default seekbar.
TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter));
// we are adding our track selector to exoplayer.
exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector);

// we are creating a variable for datasource factory and setting its user agent as 'exoplayer_view'
DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("exoplayer_video");

DashMediaSource dashMediaSource = new DashMediaSource(uri, dataSourceFactory,
        new DefaultDashChunkSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory), null, null);

// inside our exoplayer view we are setting our player
exoPlayerView.setPlayer(exoPlayer);

// we are preparing our exoplayer with media source.
exoPlayer.prepare(dashMediaSource);
Log.i("BW", "BW: " + bandwidthMeter.getBitrateEstimate());
// we are setting our exoplayer when it is ready.
exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```

Comment: You need to follow an obvious way for any library updating - read release notes from the oldest version to the desired one and make changes one by one.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [exoplayer release notes](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/RELEASENOTES.md) to changes made in the API, and search for removed symboles from `v2.4.0` up to the latest version. Keep in mind that `v2.x.0` versions are major releases, and mostly introduce breaking changes in the API, since exoplayer is not using semantic versioning.

For example [here](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/029a2b27cbdc27cf9d51d4a73ebeb503968849f6/RELEASENOTES.md?plain=1#L638) you can find that `ExoPlayerFactory` is removed and you should use `SimpleExoPlayer.Builder` instead.

Comment: Tnx. It could be best if u could post my code in latest version.

Comment: did u fixed that?

Comment: @mohsen If you are asking me, No, I didn't have the time to migrate the code. Actually, there are some breaking changes, and the behavior might change after migrating, so the result might not be identical.